# where will I put the codes when button is clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

i've created a macro to create a button when the sheet is activated. then i called it using the codes below: But everytime i go to different worksheet then back again to the sheet containing this button the macro does its job. i just want the macro to work when i clicked the button

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call sortData
End Sub
```

here's the code for macro that i've created:

```
 Sub sortData()
'
'     
'

'

    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(689.25, 59.25, 133.5, 30).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "sortData"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Sort Data"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=28).Font
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 12
    End With
    Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

now my problem is where will i put the codes shown below when this button is click? or simply how can i make this button worked?? i tried to put the codes in the same sheet where i called the macro but it is not working.

```
Sub sortData_Click() 'did i call the button right? but it is not working when i us it
'codes here
End Sub
```

Comment: In design mode, double-click the button, to which you want to attach the event - and Excel will automatically create the correctly named sub for you.

Comment: when i double-clicked it, it only leads me to the code or macro of the button

Comment: And this is exactly where you need to put your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the VBA Editor, click insert new module (or you can just put this in the same module where your sortData is) then write this code into your new module:

```
Sub procedureName() 'procedure name is exactly the same as what you named in Selection.OnAction = "sortData"

'codes here
End Sub
```

what you actually done is making the sortData() call itself because you have set the Selection.OnAction = "sortData" ->>> change this name to whatever procedure name you want to perform

Comment: ow i'm sorry macro5 should also be sortData. i just edited my question

Comment: @kazSone then u just rename any procedure you want to perform in the Selection.OnAct="procedure_name".i've already test this and it works okay

Comment: i've edit the answer..to make it easier, just replace Selection.OnAction = "sortData" with Selection.OnAction = "sortData_Click" and you are done

Comment: on the Selection.OnAction="procedure_name" i've change the procedure name to the macro that it needs to excute when click. now i get it. thank you very much! :)

Comment: glad it work.dont forget to accept the answer if this is what you actually want.